# Visual Studio clipboard problem

Tags: visual-studio

In all versions of Visual Studio I have used so far I have a problem with copy/paste operation. After using the application for a while(and in many cases very short while) when I copy some words or lines and paste, nothing gets pasted. Then I click ctrl+c multiple times and then the content gets copied and I can successfully paste.

This has caused me to develop a habit of always hitting ctrl+c multiple times to copy some content.

Any way to correct this?

Comment: Had the same problem in Sql Management Studio, no solution other than yours.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you delete a line with "CTRL-L" your clipboard can get messed up.

I use a small program, [ClipX](http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/) to track my clipboard. If Visual Studio deletes the item from my clipboard, I can still paste the entry.

Answer (score 1):

try doing: <kbd>CTRL + L</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused due to usage of shift + delete (it actually copies that line and deleting at the same time)

shift+delete is very handy to delete often times.